# Code terminates after saying COULD NOT CREATE KERNEL on Eclipse

Tags: c, opencl, opencl-c

I am trying to translate a sequential C code for a MJPEG decoder into OpenCL. I got the C code from [this](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/tree/master/tima_seq_version) github project.

I am now trying to convert the original C code for IDCT into OpenCL.

I copied and pasted the code from the `.c` file for IDCT and pasted into my `.cl` file which I named `invCosine.cl`.

`invCosine.cl`:

```
       #define  IDCT_INT_MIN   (- IDCT_INT_MAX - 1)
        #define  IDCT_INT_MAX   2147483647

        /*
         * Useful constants:
         */

        /*
         * ck = cos(k*pi/16) = s8-k = sin((8-k)*pi/16) times 1 << C_BITS and
         * rounded
         */
        #define c0_1  16384
        #define c0_s2 23170
        #define c1_1  16069
        #define c1_s2 22725

    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....

__kernel void idct1D(__global cl_int *Y) {
    cl_int z1[8], z2[8], z3[8];

    /*
     * Stage 1:
     */

    but(Y[0], Y[4], z1[1], z1[0]);
    rot(1, 6, Y[2], Y[6], &z1[2], &z1[3]);
    but(Y[1], Y[7], z1[4], z1[7]);
    z1[5] = CMUL(sqrt2, Y[3]);
    z1[6] = CMUL(sqrt2, Y[5]);

    /*
     * Stage 2:
     */
    but(z1[0], z1[3], z2[3], z2[0]);
    but(z1[1], z1[2], z2[2], z2[1]);
    but(z1[4], z1[6], z2[6], z2[4]);
    but(z1[7], z1[5], z2[5], z2[7]);

    /*
     * Stage 3:
     */
    z3[0] = z2[0];
    z3[1] = z2[1];
    z3[2] = z2[2];
    z3[3] = z2[3];
    rot(0, 3, z2[4], z2[7], &z3[4], &z3[7]);
    rot(0, 1, z2[5], z2[6], &z3[5], &z3[6]);

    /*
     * Final stage 4:
     */
    but(z3[0], z3[7], Y[7], Y[0]);
    but(z3[1], z3[6], Y[6], Y[1]);
    but(z3[2], z3[5], Y[5], Y[2]);
    but(z3[3], z3[4], Y[4], Y[3]);
}
```

I essentially copied and pasted the `#define` statements from original file called `idct.c`. I also copied and pasted the code for the kernel from the same `.c` file and just added the keywords `__kernel`, `__global` and `cl_int` to this kernel.  At the moment, I do not want to write an optimized OpenCL code. I simply want to offload the IDCT computations to the GPU.

My host code in the main file is as follows:

```
//////////////OpenCL parameters/////////////////////////////

            int out;
            cl_platform_id platform_id;
            cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
            cl_device_id device_id;
            cl_uint ret_num_devices;
            cl_context context;
            cl_command_queue command_queue;
            cl_program program;
            //size_t kernel_code_size;
            int *result;
            cl_int ret;
            cl_kernel kernel;
            int storeResult;


                            FILE *fp;
                            const char fileName[] = "/root/Downloads/tima_seq_version/src/invCosine.cl";
                            size_t source_size;
                            char *source_str;

                         /* Load kernel source file */
                         fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
                         if (!fp) {
                             fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
                             exit(1);
                         }


                         source_str = (char *)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
                     source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
                     fclose(fp);

        /////////Set platform, context, command-queue.........../////////////////////////

            /* Get Platform */
              ret= clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
               if (ret_num_platforms == 0)
                  {
                      printf("Found 0 platforms!\n");
                  return EXIT_FAILURE;
                  }
               /* Get Device */
               ret= clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
               printf("Number of devices: %d\n", ret_num_devices);

               /* Create Context */
               context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

               if (!context)
               {
                   printf("NO cCONTEXT\n");
                   return EXIT_FAILURE;

               }

               /* Create Command Queue */
               command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

               if (!command_queue)
               {
                   printf("NO command queue\n");
                   return EXIT_FAILURE;

               }

                /* Create kernel from source */
                          program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

                          if (!program)
                          {
                              printf("NO PROGRAM!!!!\n");
                              return EXIT_FAILURE;
                          }

                          clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, "", NULL, NULL);

                       if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
                              printf("building program failed\n");
                              if (ret == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) {
                                  size_t log_size;
                                  clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);
                                  char *log = (char *) malloc(log_size);
                                  clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, log, NULL);
                                  printf("%s\n", log);
                              }
                          }

                 kernel= clCreateKernel(program, "idct1D", &ret);

               if( !kernel || ret != CL_SUCCESS)
               {
                   printf("-----COULD NOT CREATE KERNEL!!---\n");
                   exit(1);
               }
```

When I run the application, I get the following output:

```
Number of devices: 2
-----COULD NOT CREATE KERNEL!!---
```

In order to understand why the kernel is not being detected, I removed all my idct code and copied and pasted the kernel code from [this](https://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/calling-the-kernel/) link into my .cl file:

```
__kernel void taskParallelAdd(__global float* A, __global float* B, __global float* C)  
{   
    int base = 0;

    C[base+0] = A[base+0] + B[base+0];
    C[base+4] = A[base+4] + B[base+4];
    C[base+8] = A[base+8] + B[base+8];
    C[base+12] = A[base+12] + B[base+12];
}
```

When I ran the application again, it ran smoothly and did not produce the same error.

**Why is my idct kernel not being detected?**

P.S. I am using the Eclipse IDE for writing and running my code.

Comment: You are not testing return value of `clBuildProgram`. I suspect it may be failing and that the resulting error message retrieved via `clGetProgramBuildInfo` may reveal the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the kernel error is, you are not actually checking the error code in you `clBuildProgram` call. If you run `ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, "", NULL, NULL);` instead, you will get an error in clBuildProgram call.

The reason you are getting that error is, OpenCL C language does not have `cl_int` data type. Which means you cannot use it inside kernel. cl_* types are for host side usage. Inside a .cl file like yours, you need to use regular types such as int, float, char etc.

Assuming the code you provided has all the necessary definitions to `but` and `rot` macros, changing the kernel to use `int` instead of `cl_int` should fix your issue.